# How to clear data in ListAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I got following error when i want to clear all my data in `ListAdapter`

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.clear(Collections.java:1116)
        at com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.ui.AudioPlayerActivity$onComment$$inlined$apply$lambda$3$1$1.onChanged(AudioPlayerActivity.kt:300)
        at com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.ui.AudioPlayerActivity$onComment$$inlined$apply$lambda$3$1$1.onChanged(AudioPlayerActivity.kt:60)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutineLiveData.kt:97)
```

The error happened in this line `this.currentList.clear()`

```
  (recyclerView.adapter as CommentAdapter).apply {
                                                    this.currentList.clear()
                                                    submitList(it.data!!.items)
                                                }
```

Who has ideas for this question, Appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved, code as follows

```
  (recyclerView.adapter as CommentAdapter).apply {
                                                        submitList(null)
                                                        submitList(it.data!!.items)
                                                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

when youre calling `this`, its referencing the adapter and not on your list!

you should invoke `.clear()` on the list not on recyclerview adapter, as it is a method for Arraylist not the recyclerview adapter.

```
currentList.clear()
```

and dont forget to notify

```
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Simple example:

https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-listview-remove-all-items.html

Comment: Thanks your answer,  ```currentList.clear()``` will get same result as ```this.currentList.clear()```, and that example is for ```ArrayAdapter```

Comment: you need to empty your `ArrayList` not your  `ArrayAdapter` or whatever `list` youre fetching your data from.

Comment: im pretty sure `ArrayAdapter` and `RecyclerView.Adapter` extend the same base class `Adapter`

Comment: he's talking about recycler view List adapter, not ArrayAdapter.